# Send Post Request Using xhr

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, post, xmlhttprequest

I have a very Simple API Created in node.js to get the posted Data. I am sending Form data using xhr(xml http request) of javascript.(No jquery used) But i am unable to receive form data on the server side . please help me to solve this issue. Below is the code.

Frontend Code :

```
   <form> 
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" 
         placeholder="Enter email" name="email" 

        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" 
         placeholder="Enter password" name="password" required="">

        <input type="file" class="form-control" id="userfile" name="userfile" 
         required="">

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>

  <script>
    document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click',function(){

        var email=document.getElementById('email').value;
        var password=document.getElementById('password').value;
        var fileInputElement = document.getElementById('userfile');

        var formData = new FormData();

        formData.append("email", email);
        formData.append("password", password);
        formData.append("userfile", fileInputElement.files[0]);

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost:3000/form_submit");
        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form- 
        urlencoded");
        xhr.send(formData); 
    })
  </script>
```

Backend Code (Node js API Code) :

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
  console.log('you are welcome');
}) 
app.post('form_submit',function(req,res){
  console.log('entered in post request');
  console.log(req.body);
})

app.listen(3000,()=>{
  console.log('connected to 3000 port');
})
```

Comment: @Rajat- please check my answer

Answer (score 0):

To allow express to handle form data you need to use bodyParser module:

Use bodyParser.urlencoded() middleware as:

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
//Now you can get the form values will be on req.body:

app.post('form_submit',function(req,res){
  console.log('entered in post request');
  console.log(req.body);
})
```

FYI:**Please note that body-parser doesn't handle multipart bodies, so in this case you can use a module like [multer](http://%20https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer)**

> Multer is a node.js middleware for handling multipart/form-data, which is primarily used for uploading files.

For example, to retrieve the (regular) fields of a request:

```
let multer = require('multer');
let upload = multer();
 app.post('form_submit', upload.fields([]), (req, res) => {
      let formData = req.body;
      console.log('form data', formData);
 });
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your Efforts NullPointer , But it doesn't work for me . I have already tried all of these and again tried.